# Sorting JSON's in array by date, but extend date for accept 13 month

Tags: javascript, json, date

i have this function that will do what i want, sort a array of json objects by date, but i need improve to accept the 13 month (salary).

```js
module = {};
module.exports = [
    {
        "date": "01-2012"
    },
    {
        "date": "12-2011"
    },
    {
        "date": "01-2014"
    },
    {
        "date": "08-2015"
    },
    {
        "date": "13-2014"
    }
];

document.getElementById("exports").innerHTML = JSON.stringify( module.exports ) ;

function parseMyDate( date_value ) {
    return new Date( date_value.replace(/([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{4})/, "$2-$1-01") );
}

module.exports.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseMyDate( a.date ) - parseMyDate( b.date );
});


document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML = JSON.stringify( module.exports ) ;
```

```html
<h1>module.exports unsorted</h1>
<pre id="exports"></pre>

<h1>module.exports sorted</h1>
<pre id="sorted"></pre>
```

This is possible?

I'm using this in a node.js env, so i could easy use some package that extends the date, but i didn't found.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a terrible problem description. Please explain in proper detail what expectations are...and why there is a 13th month and what should be done with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **parseMydate** function needed to be changed to handle non-dates. I turned the value into an integer YYYYMM which will work for your sort.

**update** - Now handles single digit month.

```js
module = {};
module.exports = [{
  "date": "1-2012"
}, {
  "date": "12-2011"
}, {
  "date": "1-2014"
}, {
  "date": "8-2015"
}, {
  "date": "13-2014"
}];

document.getElementById("exports").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(module.exports);

function parseMyDate(date_value) {
  return date_value.replace(/([0-9]{1,2})\-([0-9]{4})/, function(m, a, b) {
    return parseInt(b, 10) * 100 + parseInt(a, 10);
  });
}

module.exports.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseMyDate(a.date) - parseMyDate(b.date);
});


document.getElementById("sorted").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(module.exports);
```

```html
<h1>module.exports unsorted</h1>
<pre id="exports"></pre>

<h1>module.exports sorted</h1>
<pre id="sorted"></pre>
```

Comment: Yeap, that's what i need. I didn't get what you did, could you explain?

Comment: Cool, only the function name needs to be changed since it isn't parsing the strings, just reordering the components. There's also no need for *parseInt*. There needs to be a bit of work on the RegExp as dates like `9-2015` will not sort correctly with `08-2015`.

Comment: @RobG Hm, i think i didn't understood, this script doesn't work?

Comment: @user98293989823—it works fine, but allowing 1 digit months needs to be dealt with. Either throw an error (don't allow them) or use a leading zero when concatenating after the year (fix them).

Comment: Is possible to insert only with regex? I mean, the regex insert if observe that doesn't exist?

Comment: @user98293989823 It's just a reordering of the digits so year is first. 1-2014 get's parsed to  1 and 2014 then I make room for the month with 2014 * 100 = 201400 then add the month 201400 + 1 = 201401. The new method allows for single digit months.